# error with select2 does not appear correctly

Tags: php, jquery-select2, codeigniter-4

Greetings I hope you can help me
the problem is that when I use select 2 it generates 2 select

without the select I get like this

```
<select class="form-control" style="width:50%;" name="" id="">
<option value="">rr</option>
<option value="">dd</option>
</select>
```

add example
[image]

but when I add the select2 I get like this

```
<select class="form-control select2" style="width:50%;" name="" id="">
    <option value="">rr</option>
    <option value="">dd</option>
</select>

    <script>
$(document).ready(function () {

  $(".select2").select2();
});

</script>
```

add example2
[image]

Answer (score 0):

```js
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.js-example-basic-single').select2();
        });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
    <title>Teste</title>
</head>
<body>

    <select class="js-example-basic-single" style="width:50%;" name="put-name-here" id="put-id-here">
        <option value="">rr</option>
        <option value="">dd</option>
    </select>
    
    
    
</body>
</html>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-w1Q4orYjBQndcko6MimVbzY0tgp4pWB4lZ7lr30WKz0vr/aWKhXdBNmNb5D92v7s" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <title>Teste</title>
</head>
<body>

    <select class="form-select form-select" name="put-name-here" id="put-id-here">
        <option value="">rr</option>
        <option value="">dd</option>
    </select>

</body>
</html>
```

As I understand it using select2 plugin, right?

This is because you are mixing form-control, a bootstrap class, with select2 which also has its own css parameters.

I don't think it's advisable to mix the two. Either use select2 and its classes for selects as in their documentation or use bootstrap. Personally I would only use the bootstrap.

There is a project that uses both for version 3 of the bootstrap, but I never used it.

http://select2.github.io/select2-bootstrap-theme/

for use select2:

```
<select class="js-example-basic-single" style="width:50%;" name="put-name-here" id="put-id-here">
    <option value="">rr</option>
    <option value="">dd</option>
</select>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.js-example-basic-single').select2();
    });

</script>
```

For use bootstrap :

```
<select class="form-select form-select-sm" name="put-name-here" id="put-id-here">
    <option value="">rr</option>
    <option value="">dd</option>
</select>
```

Comment: and then how can I put it to work for me because if I only put classes = select I get the same distorted

Comment: Se você for usar somente o bootstrap é só retirar o script e a classe e utilizar somente classes bootstrap.

Caso queira usar mesmo o select2 tem que retirar as classes bootstrap, no seu caso, o form-control e retirar a classe select2. Adicionar a classe especifica do select2 como por exemplo: js-example-basic-single e ative o javascript da mesma forma que está fazendo.

Comment: i will edit my answer for include this exemple

Comment: I still get this error as two different ones are made like the photo and I already put in the two ways that I explain myself

Comment: I put it on code snippet for yor test. if doesn't work. Can you put it on git for a test ?

Comment: Maybe your css CDN is not loading (if you use CDN).

Comment: Did that help you?
If so, please mark as resolved.